# Как наилучшим образом "смержить" два JSONObject?

Tags: android, java, json

Имеем:

```
JSONObject o1 = {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3"
}
JSONObject o2 = {
        "four": "4",
        "five": "5",
        "six": "6"
    }
```

В результате слияния `o1` и `o2` должны получить:

```
JSONObject result = {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3",
        "four": "4",
        "five": "5",
        "six": "6"
    }
```

Один из вариантов - использвать иторатор по `keys`, и пока `hasNext` - добавлять поле по ключу в новый объект.

Ищу более красивый способ.

Note - Ключи в `o1` и `o2` повторяться не могут.

Comment: тут есть еще одна важная деталь - что должно произойти, если в ваших объектах есть свойства с одинаковыми ключами?

Comment: @DreamChild, я вроде в последней строке вопроса написал, что "Ключи в o1 и o2 повторяться не могут."

Comment: вот такую вот [штуку][1] нашел... Библиотека, расширяющая возможности JSON.


  [1]: http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/json-simple/merge-json-object.html

Comment: @metalurgus, спасибо. Но хочу решить эту задачу, используя стандартные средства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пришел к тому, что наилучшим решением будет использования иторатора `jsonObject.keys()` и ручной сборки результурующего объекта.

```
public JSONObject mergeJsonObjects(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    Iterator i1 = o1.keys();
    Iterator i2 = o2.keys();
    String tmp_key;
    while (i1.hasNext())
    {
        tmp_key = (String) i1.next();
        try {
            result.put(tmp_key, o1.get(tmp_key));
        }catch (JSONException ignored){}  
    }
    while (i2.hasNext())
    {
        tmp_key = (String) i2.next();
        try {
            result.put(tmp_key, o2.get(tmp_key));
        }catch (JSONException ignored){}
    }
    return result;
}
```

upd:

```
public JSONObject mergeJsonObjects(ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        String tmp_key;
        for (JSONObject jsonObject: jsonObjects){
            Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                tmp_key = (String) iterator.next();
                try {
                    result.put(tmp_key, jsonObject.get(tmp_key));
                }catch (JSONException ignored){}
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: А зачем ?

Достаточно просто дописать из o1 в o2. Если не хотите что бы объект о2 менялся - клонируйте его. Зачем делать лишнюю работу ?

Comment: Я подумал о вашем комментарии, и пришел к выводу, что стоит сделать более унифицированный метод.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел вот такое [решение](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/json/json-simple/merge-json-object.html):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("name", "Sriram");
jsonObj.put("age", 2);
jsonObj.put("hobby", "painting");

JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject();
jsonObj2.put("hobby", "Singing");
jsonObj2.put("dob", new Date(110, 4, 6));

jsonObj.putAll(jsonObj2);
System.out.println(jsonObj);
```

На выходе:

```
{"dob":Thu May 06 00:00:00 IST 2010,"age":2,"name":"Sriram","hobby":"Singing"}
```

Comment: @ua6xh, к сожалению метода .putAll(..) в пространсве имен  org.json.JSONObject нет. [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Ваш пример использует стороннюю библиотеку. А подключать ее только из-за такой мелочи - не вижу смысла.

Comment: @jimpanzer - Да, не глянул в доки JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

Конвертируем JSON-объект в строку:

```
String str1 = o1.toString();
```

Находим последнюю фигурную скобку в строке и заменяем её на запятую:

```
int index1 = str1.lastIndexOf("}");
str1 = new StringBuilder(str1).replace(index1, index1+1, ",").toString();
```

Аналогично для второго объекта, только заменяем "{" на предыдущюю строку:

```
String str2 = o2.toString();
int index2 = str1.indexOf("{");
str2 = new StringBuilder(str2).replace(index2, index2+1, str1).toString();
```

Конвертируем обратно в JSON-объект:

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(str2);
```

Но это явно **не наилучший** способ.

Comment: "не наилучший" - да это просто извращение.

Comment: @jimpanzer, а мне понравился этот способ. Должен вроде быстрее работать, чем итерация по всем ключам...

Comment: — О! Месье знает толк в извpащениях! (c)

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы и нет.
Пишется простейшая функция:

```
    public JSONObject sliv (JSONObject name1, JSONObject name2 ) throws JSONException {

    String str1 = name1.toString();

    int index1 = str1.lastIndexOf("}");
    str1 = new StringBuilder(str1).replace(index1, index1+1, ",").toString();


    String str2 = name2.toString();
    int index2 = str1.indexOf("{");

    str2 = new StringBuilder(str2).replace(index2, index2+1, str1).toString();

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(str2);

    return result;
}
```

Просто обращайтесь: `sliv (JSONObject (Ваш объект 1), JSONObject (Ваш объект 2) )`